# Sanitize python slice?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using Python/ctypes to wrap a C library. One of the structures I am wrapping resembles a numerical vector, and I would like the **getitem**() method of the corresponding Python class to support slices. At the C - level I have slice-aware function like this:

```
void * slice_copy( void * ptr , int index1 , int index2 , int step) {  
...  
}
```

My Python **getitem**() looks like this:

```
def __getitem__(self , index):  
   if isinstance( index , types.SliceType):
      # Call slice_copy function ...
      # Need values for arguments index1, index2 and step.  
   elif isinstance( index , types.IntType):
      # Normal index lookup
   else:
      Raise TypeError("Index:%s has wrong type" % index)
```

If the slice literal looks like [1:100:10] the start,end and step properties of the slice object are all set, but e.g. in the case [-100:] the start property will be -100 and both the end and step properties will be None, i.e. they need to be sanitized before I can pass integer values to the C function slice_copy(). Now, this sanitizing is not very difficult, but I would have thought that the necessary functionality was already included in the Python source - or?

Comment: I'd usually use `isinstance(index, int)` and `isinstance(index, slice)` for brevity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a function in the interface.  `slice` objects have an `indices()` method that accepts the length of the sequence as parameter and returns the normalised start, stop and step values as a tuple.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the investigation - Joakim.